# How to send all events of a child control to its parent control (custom control)?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one custom control containing three child controls (Panel with PictureBox control and Label) and I want to send all events of a child controls to its parent control (custom control).

I know there are lots of answers regarding this problem, but I cannot figure out it with a simple solution.

Here is my example

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();
        this.Controls.Add(uc1);
    }
}

public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public PictureBox ChildPictureBox { get; set; }

    public UserControl1()
    {
        PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
        pictureBox1.Size = new Size(150, 150);
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        pictureBox1.Click += PictureBox1_Click;
        this.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
        ChildPictureBox = pictureBox1;

        this.Click += UserControl1_Click;
    }

    private void UserControl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("User control click");
    }

    private void PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("pic clicked");
    }      
}
```

Comment: Here is an example I wrote about how to register an event from the child control to the parent control. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934376/main-control-to-close-child/31934727#31934727
If you are still unsure about what to do, ask, and I will try and answer

Answer (score 2):

The following code is the example, here `UserControl1` has `PictureBox` and `Panel` and their click events are hooked into `MainForm` i-e `MyForm` as named. You can modify it as per your requirements.

UserControl1.cs

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public delegate void PictureBoxClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event PictureBoxClickHandler PictureBoxClick;

    public delegate void PanelClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event PanelClickHandler PanelClick;

    public delegate void PictureBoxDoubleClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event PictureBoxDoubleClickHandler PictureBoxDoubleClick;

    public delegate void PictureBoxMouseMoveHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e);
    public event PictureBoxMouseMoveHandler PictureBoxMouseMove;

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PictureBoxClick != null)
        {
            PictureBoxClick(sender, e);
        }
    }

    private void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PanelClick != null)
        {
            PanelClick(sender, e);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PictureBoxDoubleClick != null)
        {
            PictureBoxDoubleClick(sender, e);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PictureBoxMouseMove != null)
        {
            PictureBoxMouseMove(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

MyForm.cs

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var userControl1 = new UserControl1();
        Controls.Add(userControl1);
        userControl1.PictureBoxClick += userControl1_PictureBoxClick;
        userControl1.PanelClick += userControl1_PanelClick;

        userControl1.PictureBoxDoubleClick+=userControl1_PictureBoxDoubleClick;
        userControl1.PictureBoxMouseMove+=userControl1_PictureBoxMouseMove;
    }

    private void userControl1_PanelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Click: Panel on userControl1
    }

    private void userControl1_PictureBoxClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Click: PictureBox on userControl1
    }

    private void userControl1_PictureBoxMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void userControl1_PictureBoxDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{

    public PictureBox ChildPictureBox { get; set; }        

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ChildPictureBox = pictureBox1;
    }
    //----
}
```

Now in form

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PictureBox pictureBox = userControl1.ChildPictureBox;
        //now work with pictureBox here
        pictureBox.Click += pictureBox_Click;
    }

    private void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay this is for click event , I want child controls to attach more events like mouse double click , mouse enter , mouse move,etc. So i have to write event handler for each and every event of a child controls ?

Comment: Yes, you need to add these events just like I have added click event. Its very similar.

Comment: @ X-TE So there is no way to route all events of a child controls to parent in a simple solution ?

Comment: @userg1 Other way is that you can get PictureBox, Panel and some other childs objects on main form by adding properties in userControl1

Comment: From my question , I want the User Control click event should fire up.

Comment: As i said before that the User control click event should fire up when picture box clicked , not just picture box event.

Comment: @userg1 On main form or inside usercontrol?

Comment: Create a method inside `UserControl1` and add code which you want to perform on UserControl1 click, and call this method inside PictureBox1 click  event.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this, but you should know that uncommon events cannot be linked to other controls.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            control.Click += new EventHandler(control_Click);
        }
    }

    private void control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.UserControl1_Click(sender, e);
    }

    private void UserControl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```